# what is the use of facebook.authorizeCallback() method in facebook-android sdk?

Tags: android

what is the use of `**facebook.authorizeCallback()**` method in facebook-android sdk?

Answer (score 1):

This method must be invoked at the top of the calling activity's onActivityResult() function or Facebook authentication will not function properly! If your calling activity does not currently implement onActivityResult(), you must implement it and include a call to this method if you intend to use the authorize() method in this SDK. For more information, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent):this is what is given as api description